# Multiple JqGrids on same View/Page in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

This is **NOT** a Master/Detail question.

I am using ASP.Net MVC and trying to display several jqGrids on the same page from different data sources in a tabbed interface.

However, when the page loads each jqGrid has the layout and data for the last jqGrid that is defined on the page.  Is it possible to have two unrelated jqGrids on the same view/page?

When I load each jqGrid separately, the data displays in each one, as it should.  However, when loading all at once, it does what I said earlier.

Comment: Show how you've configured the grids (your JS file) and the actions which supply the data for the grid. We need to see them to debug them.

Comment: Thanks Craig for responding.  As an FYI, Your tutorial helped get me started.  In your defaults file for the grid (Site.Master.js), you define the variable for the grid (i.e. GridDemo.Home.GridDemo) .  The defaults file works fine if there is only one grid in the view or on the page.

However, it was a "GOTCHA" for me.  I'm using a tabbed interface (dashboard interface) so all of my grids are on one page.  Hence, everytime I created a grid on the page.  It was overwriting the other grids in my view.

I had to remove the reference to the Site.Master.js file and define the variables locally.

Comment: L A, you can override the defaults when you call `$.jqGrid` (e.g., by supplying different `url` option). The defaults don't *prevent* using multiple grids; you just can't rely on them alone.

Comment: I did override the defaults without issue, Craig. The issue was GridDemo.Home.GridDemo was referenced in each *grid.js file I created. What happens, is that variable holds a reference to each grid I have specified on that ONE view. If there is only one GRID in the view, there are no issues. However, if there are multiple grids in the same view, it utilizes the settings for the last called grid on the page including the data and columns. Your code was correct. It was, more or less, the way I'm using it with multiple grids in the View and sharing that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible. What do you mean by "load separately" - how do you load "not separately"? Can you show a bit of code? Do you use different IDs for corresponding grid's HTML elements?

Comment: Thanks for responding.   Your question, "Do you use different IDs for corresponding grid's HTML elements?" forced me to delve deeper and I figured out the issue.

The HTML elements did all have unique IDs.  However, I was using Craig Stuntz' demo and didn't realize that he was declaring the variable in the defaults file for the grid. (Site.Master.js) so each partial view was using the same variable.

Hence, the reason, each grid looked the same.

I removed the reference to the defaults file and created each grid independently without use of that file and it now works.

Comment: Glad I helped. Don't know what are those defaults that you use; I personally use a simple JS helper function so that I call createJqGrid(model, url) and all the defaults are there, with the ability to override (source code available at http://sprokhorenko.blogspot.com/2009/12/dedicated-to-my-wife.html).